# renaming an img in HTML so that it can be edited separately in CSS

Tags: html, css

I currently have several images used in my website all added in HTML which are used all for different things such as my image slider, image row and logo.

I have just added a new image page and have added a border to the images on that page using `img { border-style:ridge; }` but it has edited every single image on that whole page including logo, banner and buttons. Is there a way i can call my `<imgsrc="images/imagepage/200x2001.jpg">` image something else in html so that in css i can edit it separately without it changing every image

Comment: Yeah - just give it a class, and add `class="img-border` or something to the `<img>` tag that you want to have a border.

Comment: Also, you have no space between the tag name and the attribute

Comment: did i really deserve a -1 for this question ??

Comment: @user3350338 Strictly speaking... yes. This kind of thing is so trivially basic that literally any online tutorial would have told you about IDs and classes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erm... just use an ID?

```
<img src="..." id="derp" />
```

CSS:

```css
#derp {border-style:ridge}
```

Comment: Or a `class` for re-usable-ness :)

Comment: Thanks, im now to this and didn't know of that feature, Thankyou

Comment: This Page might help you: [w3schools - CSS: Id and Class](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That's totally true, but i haven't found an easier example for the use of id and class.